# Select a day before and after in a year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select a data in a year. But I need to select also a data a day before and after of the year.

For example:
If I select year `2014` then the result should be start from `31/Dec/2013` until `01/Jan/2015`.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, myDate) = '2014' FROM MyTable
```

My parameter is only "Year".
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @inputYear INT = 2014;

DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@inputYear -1,12,31);
DECLARE @EndDate    DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@inputYear +1,01,01);

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Comment: This is what I need. Champion!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dates using `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT
    YearDate  = DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0),
    DayBefore = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0)),
    YearAfter = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0))
```

If `@year = 2014`:

```
YearDate                DayBefore               YearAfter
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Your query should now be:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    dateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0))
    AND  < DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0)))
```

Note that for the end date, I add another day and use `<`.

Read this [article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Bertrand on why you should not use `BETWEEN` and use `>=` and `<` instead.